# Am I able to call a Enums constructor in Java?

Tags: java, constructor, enums

I want to make a new record in my enum list of usernames and passwords. I was going to make a method called register that would create a new record by calling the enum's constructor but when I call the constructor like this:

```
public void register(String usr, String pass) {
        DB(usr, pass); //DB is the name of my enum
}
```

I get a error saying to create a new method. How am I able to call a constructor of my enum

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should use a database, not an enum.

Comment: I hope you're not consistently passing around unhashed passwords... they should be sent once to a database for user verification and then discarded.

Comment: This isn't a legitimate program, It's just to get some practice with enum :)

Comment: An `enum` has a fixed number of instances which are initialised when the class is loaded.  If you need to change them later, you can do this, but this doesn't mean you are calling a constructor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Enums are types with a closed set of instances. These instances are defined at class-design time (they are defined in the source code of the enum).

You cannot add enum instances at runtime. Enum constructors are private by language restrictions.

Comment: If so, you should accept it so that others can see that it solved the question.